# Vue 2 + Bootstrap 4 tooltip

Tags: jquery, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

Faced a little problem during creation new vue component.
I need to add dynamically tooltips inside vue v-for. This is my method:

```
  addTooltip() {
    $(this.$el).tooltip({
      trigger: 'hover',
      title: this.toolTipTitle(),
      placement: 'right',
      delay: {
        show: 300,
        hide: 300
      }
    })
  }
```

And this is how I call it inside mounted:

```
 this.addTooltip()
```

Everything works perfectly, except one annoying vue warning (see attached image)

[image]

Will appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Can you set up an example of this that we can debug?

Comment: fyi, if you're doing any jquery on top of vue, it's better recommended to modify the dom using jquery not vue. So instead of v-for, you'd want to use $.each

Comment: @sksallaj Thanks!